# How do I add meta title/description and intro text to a Channel index page?

Tags: channels

I've created a Channel with templates `blog/index` and `blog/_entry`. Template `blog/index` will list the blog articles and `blog/_entry` will display individual blog articles. I want to have meta title/description and some intro text on the `blog/index` page that is managed by Craft. How can this be done?

Comment: You just want to display each blog entry's title and description on the index page?

Answer (score 1):

From the docs:

Singles

Singles are used for one-off pages that have unique content requirements, such as:

- home page
- an About Us page
- a Contact Us page

Unlike the other section types, Singles only have one entry associated with them, and they don’t have an editable Author, Slug, Post Date, or Expiration Date.

---

So create the fields you need, create a new single for your index page, add the fields to the single, set the single to load your index template, then code your new fields into the template